# Is it a security vulnerability if the addresses of university students are exposed?

Tags: privacy, vulnerability

I am sorry for my lack of knowledge in this matter.

My university (basically an international university in the UK that has students from different countries) has a website which requires the students to login before they can access their examination results. These results also include their Name and Address.

But by inspecting the network transaction, I found out that it went to a page that directly takes student registration number in the URL and displays the examination result related to that. This page can be accessed without logging in to the student account and without any hassle, it gave me the examination result that exposed the student name and address. I tried multiple registration numbers similar to mine and all were processed easily.

Another problem is that these registration numbers are in fixed length, only contain numbers and are in ascending order. So for example if a valid registration number is 000001 then the next one would be 000002 and so on.

So in my opinion an attacker can easily create an automated program that could generate these registration numbers, randomly or in order, and get the names and addresses of hundreds of students.

My questions are:

1. Is it universally approved practice for universities to expose the names and addresses of students?
2. Is it universally approved practice for universities that strong security related to name and address is not important?
3. Is it a severe attack and do I have to report it to them? Or can it simply be ignored?

**Update:**

I received the reply from the university and they have now fixed it. **Thanks to all of you.**

Comment: If the University is in the UK, this may be a breach of the Data Protection Act and if it is not immediately fixed by the University, it can be reported to the [Information Commissioner's Office](https://ico.org.uk/concerns/handling/) who may decide to take further action.

Comment: Where is this university? Are the grades also publicly accessible?

Comment: You might consider reporting this anonymously.

Comment: If I understood correctly you are saying that your university has a page where, given the matriculation number of a student, they give you name and postal address (or email address?), and possibly the grade of an exam?

Comment: @daiscog the university is based in UK.

Comment: @Josh yes I am really worried about on how to report it, I think reporting anonymously would be much better. Thanks.

Comment: @daiscog thanks for the link, I will look into it.

Comment: @Bakuriu, yes totally correct. But by display it first ask for student username and password before they give the report, If we use the vulnerability we can bypass that login and see the report without logging in.

Comment: @GhulamAli As long as you guys still are in the EU, that's a very serious problem your university has there. It's clearly illegal under EU law.

Comment: Unless you took steps to hide your IP address during the original accesses, you can't really report it fully anonymously.

Comment: @daiscog's comment is really the best answer, I think. Since the university is in the UK, this is almost certainly a breach of the DPA (violation of principle 7, and probably 6 and 8 as well). The university should have a DPA office/officer who will go ballistic when you report this (and I think you should), and should be able to get very senior pressure applied to change it. If they don't fix it promptly, then a report to the ICO, as suggested, would be proper.

Comment: The question asked in the title, "Is it a security vulnerability if...", has a fundamentally ambiguous answer even in such a clear-cut scenario. The phrase "security vulnerability" can be defined as "something surprising that you can do with a system you control" and while this case is semi-objective in the sense that "well it would certainly surprise the government regulators who would presumably issue a steep fine!" it still has a lot of these hallmarks of subjectivity.

Comment: Would *you* want your address and name leaked?

Comment: I thank that accessing these pages about any student other than yourself, while understanding that the university was intending to keep them private, would be a crime under [section 1 of the computer misuse act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1)

Comment: "by inspecting the network transaction" - does this also imply the connection is not protected with an SSL cert?

Comment: If the students' addresses are just mail boxes at the campus post office this would be less egregious - but still bad.

Comment: @w3d the connection was https but website was using Ajax so I looked into the HTML source and found the clear link it was using.

Comment: @emory No it's not mail boxes at campus. It's their personal address.

Comment: Usually, anything that's related to the word "exposed" is bad.

Comment: If/when you report it, I'd suggest highlighting the fact that you can see other student's grades. That's more likely to be a violation than having their addresses public. Twice, I reported similar issues to my previous college, and the issue was always well received and fixed quickly once it got to the right person.

Comment: @GhulamAli Just out of curiosity, did you get a chance to report it? If yes, has any action been taken from the admin side?

Comment: @PriyankGupta Yes I reported it 4days ago. No reply yet. But the automated response to that email address said that they will respond within 5days.

Comment: So I got the reply, the person told me he forwarded my email to relevant department where the issue will be discussed and they will be in touch with me if needed. I will update if I get any further message.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> I am sorry for my lack of knowledge in this matter.

You shouldn't be.

> Is it universally approved practice for universities to expose the name and addresses of students?

As pointed out in comments, it depends on your local laws and regulations. You should certainly check it once. But the way you describe the application(changing the URL to get the details, including the result), it sounds like a bug, which should certainly be reported.

> Is it universally approved practice for universities that strong security related to name and address is not important?

No, be it a university or a big MNC or a small enterprise, or your own personal account, security is ALWAYS important.

> Is it a severe attack and do I have to report it to them? Or it can be simply ignored?

Yes, you have to report it to the university, as soon as possible. It should not be ignored.

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, there are some universities which do allow students' addresses to be made public.

Comment: Note that depending on the location of the University this could be a *huge* legal/financial liability...

Comment: @JaredSmith Or it can be completely ignored, like the case Troy Hunt covered about a website exposing health information in India https://www.troyhunt.com/43-203-indian-patient-pathology-reports-were-left-publicly-exposed-by-health-solutions/

Comment: As I point out in my answer [below](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/147245/111626), this answer is likely inaccurate. Universities in most Five Eyes countries publicly disclose "directory information" with a possibility of an opt-out.

Comment: @Jedi: OP says that he's able to access results as well, while the link you shared suggests that GPA/grades shouldn't be made public. Personally, I wouldn't want to share even my permanent address with the outside world. Also, if there's such a facility by the university, to give out the students' details, then it should be in an elegant way. The way OP describes the situation(registration number in the URL), it sounds like a bug in the website.

Comment: @PriyankGupta exactly. Universities divide FERPA-class information into two categories "directory" and "private". Grades, DoB is private, contact information and address is not. `No, exposing the names and addresses is a serious breach of privacy.` This statement is hence inaccurate. Exposing names and addresses is allowed by the privacy policy of US/UK/etc. universities. This does not mean that security or privacy of your personal information is not important. OP should check the relevant laws that apply to his country. The upvotes on this answer would mean that Stanford, MIT, CMU are wrong?

Comment: @Jedi: Now that I have an example of Virginia Tech, I have edited the answer. Thanks for your inputs! :)

Comment: @PriyankGupta not to be argumentative but the answer is still inaccurate. It isn't the university that decides. The relevant law, i.e. FERPA in the US requires that `A student's directory information may be released to an inquirer...` and students must individually opt out. Universities could/should be more privacy-sensitive and make it easier to opt out, but to call it a severe attack without knowing the facts is rushing to judgment. OP should first check the relevant laws and how they apply and [fill out a form if needed](https://www.cmu.edu/hub/ferpa.html).

Comment: @PriyankGupta:  At the University of Cambridge, grades are public information (they are published on the walls of the Senate House).  OTOH, if this is a UK university, the ICO will be distinctly unimpressed.

Comment: @Jedu At a college I used to work at in the USA, this would be a **huge** deal. We had a student murdered by an abusive ex because somebody gave him info about her that they shouldn't have. Maybe it's not breaking any laws in 99.999% of cases, but that one student that did opt out may have had very good reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith most organisations will have a clause in the contract/T&C/etc that basically says you give them permission to do whatever they want with your information to prevent being held liable when glitches like this happen.

Comment: @Aequitas having said contract clause and having it *actually* hold up in court are two different things. Also, universities live and die by recruiting, which is based on public perception. No school would want that kind of PR hit.

Comment: @Kat V, The original answer painted with a broad brush, and was hence inaccurate. I have no quarrels with the answer as it stands. It's good to hear about a university taking proactive measures to improve privacy. However, do they back up their actions with a written policy that guarantees this to students? Public perception is overrated.

Comment: Even though many universities operate a public directory, there is often a way to opt-out or for some information to be non-public, precisely because of situations like the one @Kat mentioned. It is, of course, possible that the information here is just exactly the same as that published in a publicly available directory, but that should be investigated as part of determining the severity of this vulnerability.

Comment: @MartinBonner big difference between publishing on a wall somewhere and being able to access them online through a possible unintentional website glitch.

Comment: The fundamental problem is violating an expectation of privacy.  If students expect the school to make their address public when they give the school that information there is no problem.  If they don't, and the school lets them be exposed, it's a serious problem.  The local laws just define how much trouble the school is in.  Even if they didn't apply there is a moral imperative here.

Comment: If the college decides to make the info public by default, they should explicitly mention it while admitting the students, so that the students aren't under any kind of false impression.

Answer (score 50):

This is a vulnerability, the way they have used sequenced guessable numbers to access records is a class of vulnerability called Insecure Direct Object Reference and is featured in the OWASP Top 10 (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References)

Depending on where in the world you live, the university may be contravening data protection laws. At the very least it is poor data control and violates your personal privacy, you should certainly tell them about this.

Answer (score 25):

Since the university is in the UK, this is almost certainly a breach of the [DPA 1998](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29).  That is, this is not narrowly a ‘security’ issue.

A student home address would certainly count as ‘personal data’ within the terms of the Act.  The fact that you can retrieve the data in this way is, I'm very sure, a violation of principle 7, and probably 6 and 8 as well).  The principles are that [personal data must be](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/schedule/1)

1. fairly and lawfully processed;
2. processed for limited purposes;
3. adequate, relevant and not excessive;
4. accurate;
5. not kept for longer than is necessary;
6. processed in line with users’ rights;
7. secure; and
8. not transferred outwith the EEA.

The fact that you had to *very* mildly hack this to get the information doesn't change things: it means that it isn't secure.  Principle 7, in full, is ‘Appropriate technical and organisational measures shall be taken against unauthorised or unlawful processing of personal data and against accidental loss or destruction of, or damage to, personal data.’

A final degree classification would count as public data, in the sense that part of your contract with the university is that they would tell people that you've graduated.  Internal/intermediate marks would probably not count as public data (and that ‘probably’ means that there would have to be a positive argument that they did count as public, before it was OK to make them available like this).

The university should have a DPA office/officer who will go ballistic when you report this to them (and I think you should), and should be able to get very senior pressure applied to change it.  They might not seem to make much of a fuss in response to your report, but I hope they would take immediate action internally.  If they don't fix it promptly (or perhaps even if you don't see immediate *evidence* that they have done so), then a [report to the ICO](https://ico.org.uk/concerns/handling/), as suggested by @daiscog's comment, would be proper.

Regarding the question of reporting this anonymously, you could if you want, but I would hope it wouldn't matter, and that the DP Office would be appropriately discreet (this is very much their problem, not yours).  If there were any comeback, I'm sure the ICO would be *extremely* interested to hear about that.

I'm in effect the DP officer in our (UK) university department, and I know how I or the university DP office would respond to hearing about this.

(I originally posted this as a comment, but on reflection expanded it into an answer)

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that it is by design, and not thought of as leakage of sensitive information. If you were to look at directories online, [MIT](http://web.mit.edu/people.html), [CMU](https://directory.andrew.cmu.edu), [Stanford](https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/), and any others I think of all publicly list students and staff directories.

Universities in the United States are generally more concerned about [FERPA](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html?src=rn), which protects student education records.

"Directory information" such as name, address, enrollment status and dates are not protected by default. [Here](https://registrar.uoregon.edu/sites/registrar2.uoregon.edu/files/pdf/UO_Directory_Information_Chart.pdf)'s a good list of what qualifies as directory information and can be revealed to the public. The relevant stipulation reads:

> A student's directory information may be released to an inquirer, outside the University, unless the student specifically requests that directory information be withheld.

If I were you, I would look around for a privacy policy before contacting the university. It is likely intentional. Your university likely has an opt-out clause to protect your directory information.

Also, most websites have their directories on do-not-crawl lists so  that your records are not online on search engines. You may wish to check the [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

That being said, grades should never be disclosed. [In practice, under a rare FERPA case](http://www.educationworld.com/a_issues/issues279.shtml), grades refer to letter/transcript grades and not individual classroom scores which are sometimes considered to be "lecturer notes".

Comment: None of the university pages you linked show student or staff addresses. They only show student names, campus id's, and school emails.

Comment: To support @Jedi, I can confirm that Virginia Tech certainly shows student addresses of anyone who doesn't opt-out. search.vt.edu/people.jsp

Comment: @Yay295: searching for Aiken on Stanford's directory [gives me all his information](https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/detailAction.do?key=DS036G974&search=aiken&soundex=&stanfordonly=&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed) (not sure if the link will persist). My university reveals my details and I followed up with them to learn about the relevant FERPA sections.

Comment: @Jedi, that appears to be the exception, not the rule. I checked 100 random results, and only 4 of them showed their home address. If you had to opt-out to hide this information, I would have expected it to be higher, so it seems likely that these people have specifically chosen to release their home address.

Comment: Up until 2014 MIT displayed all this info in its directory https://thetech.com/2014/07/09/mitpeople-v134-n29

Comment: @Yay295 the way it works at my university (for home addresses / telephone numbers) is that you fill out a form providing the information to the university, which you typically do as faculty, staff or a paid teaching/research assistant. My point is not that displaying address information is widespread/common, but that it is lawful. I quote the relevant portions of FERPA that are applicable.

Comment: robots.txt is not a security measure (in particular when it says "dear google, please don't look at supersecretpage", this may rather help attackers to find it)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen good point. In this case it is used as intended. It is meant to prevent indexing of contact information by "nice" crawlers so they don't turn up on a Google search for example.

Comment: Even though OP did only explicitly ask about directory information, in my opinion you should put more emphasis on your last paragraph: By linking other information to the directory information, this becomes a huge issue which should be addressed!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The OP is in the UK and therefore UK/EEA/EU laws apply. Personal information is any data, or combination of data, that can be used to identify and individual, which name and address certainly is. This data should never have been released.

Comment: @Ben, I missed OP's location update. I will update the answer accordingly to indicate that it only holds for the USA.

Answer (score 5):

Although an answer has been accepted and both Priyank and Iain make some good points, I think its worth looking at the question of whether this is sensitive data in more depth.

First off, there is something of a difference between exam results (typically a student will have many exams during their course of study) and qualifications (i.e. the final award by the institution). So it is also possible to infer whether an individual is currently a student.

This information opens the door to all sorts of targeted phishing - people pretending to be a student loan provider, offering refinancing or pretending to be official alumni organizations.

It is also a great asset for identity fraud. While I've never come across a [wish-it-was-two-factor](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/WishItWas-TwoFactor-) question about higher education ("What was our first school" still seems common) such a facility would facilitate fraudulent job/credit applications.

Hence, the question about whether this falls within the organizations privacy policy or local regulation is moot: it constitutes a dereliction of the providers duty of care to their students/graduates.

But the flip side of this is that it seems crazy to me that the only way I can prove what degrees I have to someone who asks (e.g. a prospective employer) is to show them a bit of paper (relatively easy to fake). But I imagine that most people reading this would be able to think simple, effective solutions to securely revealing such information.

Comment: IME companies simply call the school to confirm graduation. I only recall an overseas jobs asking for transcripts due to a law. Never in the states.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I am mostly concerned that the system reveals the **registration ID** of the students.

I don't know how things are at your university, but in my time as a student, we wrote the RI on our exam answer sheets so that the graders wouldn't know who was who.

At your university, the graders can look up who is who and that is, in my opinion, a severe security breach.

Comment: Faculty can look up registration IDs anyway--at any university I've worked at, and I'm sure anywhere else. How else would the grades be associated with the right student? The point is that, while grading, they don't know who the number corresponds to, to reduce unconscious bias.

Answer (score 3):

If the information on student grades can personally identify an individual, this
is almost certainly an issue. If on the other hand, all you can see are the
grades associated with some unknown individual i.e. associated with some number,
but you cannot determine precisely who that number represents, then it may not
be considered a security issue as it could be argued the data has been
anonymised. A lot depends on the privacy legislation in effect (most likely the
UK legislation, but this can be affected by the country where the data is
hosted/located and the privacy policies of the institution. For example,
students might be required to agree to allowing their result data being made
public as part of the terms and conditions of enrolment. However, this is
unlikely.

Most countries have privacy legislation which determine what is considered to be
private or personal information and in some cases, impose additional
responsibilities on the hosting organisation with respect to what level of
permission they must obtain from the individual to make data public and what
actions they must take should data be accidentally disclosed or breached via
some sort of security failure. For example, in the US, if a company has an
incident where personal data is either deliberately or accidentally compromised
and that data has possible financial implications, such as exposure of credit
card details, the organisation is required to provide credit monitoring services
to affected individuals for a period of time. Some countries also have mandatory
data breach reporting and notification legislation, which requires the
organisation to notify individuals and often a central authority when data has
been compromised.

Unfortunately, governments have struggled to develop clear and consistent
legislation relating to privacy and to maintain legislation which is able to
keep pace with technology. There are significant differences between countries
with different emphasis and objectives. For example, the US has considerable
policies relating to privacy and mandatory reporting, but they also have
legislation relating to homeland security and anti-terrorism which some feel
compromises personal data privacy. Germany and a number of other European
countries have vary strong legislation to protect personal privacy. Australia
has relatively recently updated personal privacy legislation, but is struggling
to introduce mandatory data breach reporting legislation etc.

From your description, I suspect that you have indeed discovered a data access
vulnerability and you should almost certainly report it to the
University. Unfortunately, it isn't always easy to find out how to report such
issues. The first place to check would be to look at the organisation's privacy
policy. It is also likely the UK has a central authority, such as a privacy
ombudsmen, which you could also report this issue to.

You should also be aware that you need to be vary careful about accessing this
data, especially using the URL manipulation technique you described or providing
specific details regarding how to access the data. In some countries, it could
be argued that you have broken the law and you could be charged with
'hacking'. The pace of technical change combined with a lack of understanding
within the legislative and judicial systems has resulted in some poorly drafted
legislation and legal interpretation of that legislation. There have been a
number of cases where individuals have been charged for publicising data access
vulnerabilities. While such charges usually don't result in a conviction, the
potential hassles this sort of charge bring with it are best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. Especially if the university agrees to keep such information private, this could be a huge violation of their own policies.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, merely writing a simple script that scrapes such info can get you a [3.5 year sentence](https://www.wired.com/2013/03/att-hacker-gets-3-years/). If the university did no intend to make this info public, it will be considered a vulnerability.

Comment: +1 This was the answer I was thinking of. Sometimes, merely accessing a "protected" system to see anyone else's private data, no matter how lax security may be, there's always a risk that the hacker will be fined, jailed, or both.